# How to append state to another state react

Tags: reactjs

I have a state variable called database which returns an object and an array holding database names as shown below which is a dropdown menu. I want to be able to grab the value (object_name) from the databases state array and append them onto the end of the databases array from the addToProduction function. the database state variable is also living in another component.

Here is the data being returned from the database state variable:

[image]

Here is the data from the addToProduction Function:

[image]

Here is the function addToProduction....When a checkbox is checked it either adds or removes the value to the productionDatabaseState:

```
  const [productionDatabaseData, setProductionDatabaseData] = useState([])

const addToProduction = ({ target }, { id, databases }) => {

    setProductionDatabaseData((previousState) => {

      let newState = [...previousState]
      if (target.checked) {
        newState = [
          ...newState,
         {  unit_test_id: id, databases }
        ]
      } else {
        const i = newState.findIndex(({ unit_test_id }) => unit_test_id === id)
        if (i !== -1) newState.splice(i, 1)
      }
      return newState
    })
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("databaseArr", productionDatabaseData);
  }, [productionDatabaseData]);
```

my expected output should be like:

databaseArr:

[image]

Essentially the database state array is appended to the end of the databaseArr.

updated code:

```
  const addToProduction = ({ target }, { id, databases }) => {
  
      setProductionDatabaseData((previousState) => {
  
        let newState = [...previousState]
        if (target.checked) {
          newState = [
            ...newState,
           {  unit_test_id: id, databases }
          ]
        } else {
          const i = newState.findIndex(({ unit_test_id }) => unit_test_id === id)
          if (i !== -1) newState.splice(i, 1)
        }
        return newState
      })
      const appendedArrays = [productionDatabaseData, ...props.database.recent_objects_modified_by_user.map(({object_name}) => object_name)]

      useEffect(() => {
        console.log("databaseArr", appendedArrays);
      }, [productionDatabaseData, appendedArrays]);
  
    }
```

Update v2:

```
  const [addRemoveDatabase, setAddRemoveDatabase] = useState('prod.auiag.corp/iadpprod')
```

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't figure out where is stored the `recent_objects_modified_by_user` data is located but you can do the following assuming it's the `database` state var:

```
const appendedArrays = [productionDatabaseData, ...database.recent_objects_modified_by_user.map(({object_name}) => object_name)]
```

This is achieved by using the spread operator ([ref here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax))

Comment: Thanks! so the recent_objects_modified_by_user data is stored in that database state variable if that helps!

Comment: also database state var is living in a different component so should i be using props like this? 

const appendedArrays = [productionDatabaseData, ...props.database.recent_objects_modified_by_user.map(({object_name}) => object_name)]

Comment: and where would I be putting this?

Comment: That's right. And I don't know where do you need to use that variable so you should put that wherever is suitable

Comment: Ah cool, I've just updated my question...I am getting an error saying that TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined. Yet it is being stored in an array...Any ideas?

Comment: Yes, that's because I don't figured out which variables exactly you were talking about. Check it and it should work. I think you got the point, you should create a new array with `[]` and inside just use the spread operator of those two variables needed to "append" the items.

Comment: Ahh I see, I actually made a mistake I don't want to be pushing the database state var data but instead I want to do the addRemoveDatabase state var...which is just an array. How would I go abouts getting that value?